# I want to add a string in between of 2 strings in file, but in output whole text is getting appended at the end of file

Tags: python, file-io, append, python-2.6

Code :

```
fo = open("backup.txt", "r")

filedata = fo.read()

with open("backup.txt", "ab") as file :
   file.write(filedata[filedata.index('happy'):] + " appending text  " +     filedata[:filedata.rindex('ending')])

with open("backup.txt", "r") as file :
   print "In meddival : \n",file.read()
```

Expected Output :
I noticed that every now and then I need to Google fopen all over again. happy  appending text  ending

Actual output :
I noticed that every now and then I need to Google fopen all over again. happy endinghappy ending appending text  I noticed that every now and then I need to Google fopen all over again. happy

Comment: Expected output and actual output displays the text displayed in file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this will definitely fix your problem.

```
fo = open("backup.txt", "r")

filedata = fo.read()

ix = filedata.index('ending')
new_str = ' '.join([filedata[:ix], 'appending text', filedata[ix:]])

with open("backup.txt", "ab") as file:
   file.write(new_str)

with open("backup.txt", "r") as file :
   print "In meddival : \n",file.read()
```

As you can see, I am getting the index of the beginning of the `ending` word.
Then, I use `join` to make push in the `appending text` between `happy` and `ending`.

**Note** You're adding to your file another line with the changes you've made. To override the old line, replace the `a` with `w` in the `with open("backup.txt", "ab")...`

### There are more ways for doing that

You can split the string to words, find the index of the 'ending' word and `insert` the 'appending text' before it.

```
text_list = filedata.split()
ix = text_list.index('ending')
text_list.insert(ix, 'appending text')
new_str = ' '.join(text_list)
```

You can also do this one:

```
word = 'happy'
text_parts = filedata.split('happy')
appending_text = ' '.join(word, 'appending text')
new_str = appending_text.join(text_parts)
```

Comment: but as per the above statement, both start index and ending index is "ending". To print "appending text" in between of "happy" and "ending", the starting index and ending index should be different.

Comment: I understand the above concept. Hence I tried the below code

Comment: s9 = "happy ending"
print "s9 = ",s9

print "Also s9 = ", s9[s9.index('happy'):] + "appending text" + s9[:s9.rindex('ending')]

Comment: If you execute the above code, the output will be " Also s9 =  happy endingappending texthappy"

Comment: Similar output I want to be written in file. I tried in code, but no use.

Comment: Thank you.. :) The code worked properly but tiny issue is there.. After inserting text in between of strings, the whole statement of file is written again. Below is the output that I received after executing code.

Comment: beginningI noticed that every now and then I need to Google fopen all over again.  happy ending.........................................................beginningI noticed that every now and then I need to Google fopen all over again.  happy  appending text ending..

Comment: That's because you're using the `a` mode when opening the file for writing. If you will change it to `w`. Then you won't see the previous text.

Comment: First it displays the actual file content "beginning to happy ending............", then again it displays the whole file content with required output appended at the end of file.

Comment: Again -- it's because of the `a` you put in the `open('backup.txt', 'ab')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your file content

```py
fo = open("backup.txt", "r")

filedata = fo.read().split()

with open("backup.txt", "ab") as file:
   file.write(' '.join(filedata[filedata.index('happy'):]) + " appending text  " + ' '.join(filedata[:filedata.index('ending')]))

with open("backup.txt", "r") as file :
   print "In meddival : \n",file.read()
```

Comment: Getting error for file.write(filedata[filedata.index('happy'):] + " appending text  " +     filedata[:filedata.rindex('ending')]) line.










TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: Still getting error as - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rindex'

Comment: Getting error as - ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list

Comment: 'happy' or 'ending' not in your file

Comment: Its in file. File Content - beginningI noticed that every now and then I need to Google fopen all over again.  happy ending..